# Does it matter what values you assign to represent two groups in a dummy variable?

Tags: mixed-model, ordinal-data

I am conducting a Linear Mixed Effects Model analyses to evaluate the efficacy of an intervention. I have a dummy variable 'condition' which I have coded '2' for control group and '1' for intervention group. Is that okay or do I need to use a specific order (.e.g, 0 = no intervention, 1 = intervention)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your model is the following:

$$Y_i=X_i\beta+D_i\alpha$$

where $X$ is the other variables and $D$ is your dummy variable. Then for the control group your model is

$$Y_i=X_i\beta+2\alpha$$

and for intervention group

$$Y_i=X_i\beta+\alpha.$$

If you recode with 0 and 1 then respectively you get

$$Y_i=X_i\beta$$

for control group and

$$Y_i=X_i\beta+\alpha$$

for intervention group.

In the latter case $\alpha$ has a clearer interpretation. It measures the additional effect on $Y_i$ for intervention group. The interpretation in the first case is a bit trickier. That is the only difference.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clearer. I will recode this variable to ease interpretation.

Comment: adding to what mpiktas said it doesnt matter the order also in which you code intervention and nonintervention. In case your 1 tommorow means no intervention in place of intervention the sign of the coefficient will changes automatically.